# Change property on existing powershell object

Tags: powershell

I have a custom powershell object created with a function:

```
$obj = myfunction -name "hello" -value 5
```

After it's created I want to change the value property however doing it (demonstrated below) doesn't work

```
$obj.value = 1
```

I've searched and can't seem to find anything - can anybody explain how I can accomplish this?

Here is my function that creates an returns the object

```
function myfunction
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Collections.Hashtable])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0)]
        [String]
        $name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=1)]
        [int]
        $value,
    )
    Process
    {
        $myfunction = @{
            name = $name
            value = $value
        }
        write-output $myfunction
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that you have a "Custom PowerShell Object" (where everyone reads that as a "PSCustomObject" -- as highlighted by Jaqueline below). You must have some sort of .Net class which has a readonly property. Can you run $obj.GetType().FullName

Comment: I've added the function definition

Comment: If that's your function, I can't see why your other code would not work. You're returning a hashtable, and in PowerShell, hashtables CAN be accessed the way you wrote.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your problem? What is your PowerShell version? Else this should probably be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're returning a hashtable, you should be able to do what you wrote:

```
PS> $obj = myfunction -name "hello" -value 5
PS> $obj.value = 1
PS> $obj

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           hello
value                          1
```

However, the "safe" way is to use square braces.

You might want to try that, because my gut is that you tried to set `.Values` instead of `.Value` ... and `.Values` is a non-settable property of Hashtables.

```
PS> $obj = myfunction -name "hello" -value 5
PS> $obj["value"] = 1
PS> $obj

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           hello
value                          1
```

Either way, you could avoid all that by creating an actual PSCustomObject as @jaqueline-vanek did in her answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
PS C:\Users\joshua> $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ hello = 5 }
PS C:\Users\joshua> $obj.hello
5
PS C:\Users\joshua> $obj.hello = 1
PS C:\Users\joshua> $obj.hello
1
```

[PowerShell: Creating Custom Objects](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx)

Comment: Please mention where in the OP's code to put the `[PSCustomObject]` to make it work with their function.

Comment: it's not about the type but the technet article :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP is correct it does not work.
It should be,

$obj."Hello" to access the property value

$obj."Hello" = 1 to set the property.

You have to double quote the property name.